# How to migrate data between MySQL bases on different servers?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-migration

I have two tables with different schemas:

Base A, table T1:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`uid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`language` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

Base B, table T2:

```
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Type` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`UserID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

I need to transfer data from T1 to T2 in this way:

```
A.T1.id    -> B.T2.ID
A.T1.title -> B.T2.Name
A.T1.uid   -> B.T2.UserID
```

As you can see fields `A.T1.language` and `B.T2.Type` are not needed.

I think I should do this migration through dump of CSV. But this is all I have come up to.

Any idea?

**UPDATE**

Thank you guys for your answers. Please forgive me for not being clear enough, I should have emphasized that my tables are in different bases, and even on different servers. So it is not as easy as to just insert fields from one table into another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of `UPDATE` and `SELECT` query. However since `TABLE 1` has the column `title` which is of type `VARCHAR(255)` and `TABLE 2` has the column `Name` which is of type `VARCHAR(100)` might give a problem.

The following query can do this migration however any row with column `title` having length more than 100 will be **SHORTENED** to 100.

```
INSERT INTO T2 
(ID, Name, UserID) 
SELECT id, SUBSTR(title, 0, 100), uid 
FROM T1
```

Comment: Finally, I added target tables in the same base with prefixes, transferred data and then created a dump of that tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-select.html) syntax as in

```
INSERT INTO `B`.`T2` (`ID`, `Name`, `UserID`)
SELECT `id`, `title`, `uid` FROM `A`.`T1`
```

Answer (score 1):

Are they on the same database? In that case:

```
INSERT INTO T2 (ID, Name, UserID) 
SELECT id, title, uid FROM T1
```

Answer (score 1):

I there any reason why you have to add the limitation to your int fields such as INT(10) instead of just INT?

The explanation of your data transfer does not coincide with your base tables?

Anyway, the problem you might run int here is that some of your column limitations are different so you either have to make them the same or SUBSTRING them into the destination table if the string from the source column is longer than the destination column for instance if you try to insert "This is my string" into a VARCHAR(10) column, you will get a truncate error.

To insert the data into the destination table you can use this:

```
INSERT INTO [Destination Table] (ID, Name, uid)

SELECT
  ID,
  SUBSTRING(title, 0, 100) as 'Name',
  uid
FROM
  [Source Table]
```

This will work yet you will be sacrificing the data on the name column. I would suggest giving your destination columns the same data type and limitations as your source table.